importing redis in python script breaks the capture of the python output by the php script that has launched the python script
Version:
redis_version:7.2.4
redis-py : 5.0.3
Platform:
python3.12 on ubuntu22 / php 8.12 on nginx
Description:
I am executing a python process from a php script :
<?php

class execSomePythonScript {
     
  function __construct () {

     ob_start();
     passthru('/usr/bin/python3.12 pythonProc/testphp.py ';
     $output = ob_get_clean(); 

     print_r($output); exit;

  }
}

?>

the python script :
import json
output = { "c" : "b"}
print(json.dumps(output))

=> php output as expected { "c" : "b"}
However, importing redis breaks the capture of the output by php
import json
output = { "c" : "b"}
print(json.dumps(output))
import redis
print(json.dumps("c"))

=> cli output
{"c": "b"}
c

=> php output
{ "c" : "b"}

?

not sure how i fixed it (it totally came as a surprise, i had given up) but it may have been by creating a py venv installing there redis-py...
or was it by adding the www-data group to the docker image i use for redis-stack?
or both or something else in the codes i didn't realize was related... no idea :D so not posting an answer.
